# Path finding to collect enough items before the fight with the enemy

Tags: path-finding

So I have the following problem : a X by Y grid. On the grid there is a character and a monster and some items that give bonus points to the character's damage if picked and holes that must be avoided. The goal is to collect enough items to be able to defeat the monster, then navigate to the monster and fight it.

What kind of algorithm can be used to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you talking about turn based or real time gameplay? Have you considered looking at A*? The implementation looks difficult but is actually pretty simple.

Comment: Game play is real time.

Comment: Ok, you could leave some info out of your question btw. The focus here is to achieve pathfinding. Right? I'd say look at A*.

Comment: But I have to choose the path that collects enough powerups to be able to defeat the monster.

Comment: See that's the thing I couldn't read from your problem that needs solving. Could you refine your question? It seems like details are missing for what you want to achieve. As of right now I don't really have an answer to that. But if you up your questions others might be able to help you out.

Comment: How does the monster behave, is it trying to approach and kill player, or stays still, or patrols?

Comment: ...isn't this just the [travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), with a fixed endpoint?

Comment: @Trevor: close. If the asker needs the shortest such path, it's a collection of Hamiltonian path problems. If there are n items and k are needed, then there are (n Choose k) subsets to find a Hamiltonian path through, plus the start and end legs to connect to the player and monster positions. TLDR: approximate, maybe greedily. The optimum's probably too much work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do I have enough damage to defeat the monster?  If yes, go to 4.
2. Pathfind to every item, and travel to & pick up the one with the shortest path.
3. Go to 1.
4. Pathfind to the monster and defeat it.
5. End.

As others have said in the comments, [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_star) is the obvious approach for performing the pathfinding itself.